# Boost statechart, communication between separate FSMs

Tags: boost, statechart, boost-statechart

let's say I have created several separate FSM classes inheriting from statechart. Then, I instantiate those objects, and I would like them to be able to trigger events in each other; for example the first FSM would enter a "ON" state and would trigger an event in the second FSM (like process_event(EvSomething()) ).

What would be the best method to do that?

Thank you very much,

Fabrizio

Comment: Are the FMSs synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

The main motivation for [Asynchronous State Machines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html#AsynchronousStateMachines) is exactly the scenario you describe. So, I would suggest you convert your machines into asynchronous ones. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/statechart/example/PingPong/PingPong.cpp) for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after Igor's comment. Dealing with it right now. Anyway, if FSMs are not working bi-directionally (they just trigger process_event in other FSMs, but don't expect anything back), are they going to work correctly in the synchronous way?

Comment: @fabrice79: The issue is that process_event of a given state_machine subclass object is not reentrant. So, as long as you ensure that this constraint is not violated everything should work as expected.